# How can I change the sleep time of thread in run time?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-studio, thread-safety

I am developing a flashlight app. I want to change the sleep time of thread when I change the value on seek bar, but it is not implementing on runtime instead I have to stop the thread every time to get the new value of from seeking bar.`    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            value = progress;



            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "changing"+value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

**> Here the code for creating and setting the value for the thread**

```
    public void threadinit(final int value)

{

      this.value= value;



    t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            boolean stopExecution;
            final boolean toExit = false;
            //while( blinks=true)
            while (!t.isInterrupted()) {

                params = camera.getParameters();
                params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                camera.setParameters(params);
                camera.stopPreview();

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(value);
```

**Would be very thankful for your answers**

Answer (score 0):

Thread.sleep() is not guaranteed. This means that it may or may not sleep for the duration you desire for various reasons that are out of topic for this question.

check this link

[How to change the delay of sleep/timer thread in android during runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828628/how-to-change-the-delay-of-sleep-timer-thread-in-android-during-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

I would not use sleep() and interrupt() for this but rather the wait() and notify() mechanism.